# Customize position of handle of sliding drawer

Tags: java, android, slidingdrawer

I had researched many sources and tried but still cannot move the position of handle from center to right.

```
    <SlidingDrawer
        content >

        <ImageButton                                  <-- this is handle
            android:id="@+id/handle"                  <-- i want to customize position
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="60px"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_other" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_others"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            //content
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
```

So what to do to customize the position?

Please give opinion. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a TableLayout.  This works similar to a HTML Table concept, allowing you to define rows and columns where to place buttons and other components.

If you don't want to use a table layout for the entire screen, you should be able to nest the layout within another....

Comment: where to use table layout? below sliding drawer?